# How to find the lightning protection of a TVS diode?

Tags: surge-protection, tvs, st

I am using a [STmicroelectronics ESD diode SMAJ58A-TR,](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/389/cd00001333-1795517.pdf) which has a surge protection standard of IEC 61000-4-5, but they have not mentioned the value like 4kV, 6KV.

While checking in datasheet they have mentioned refer to the table.

[image]

Can anyone help me to identify the lightning protection voltage?

Comment: Look at what peak pulse power it is specified for. When looking at surge/spike immunity, what matters is how much power it can deal with for how long a time. 400W is fairly low as TVS go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *they have not mentioned the value like 4kV, 6KV*

No they don't need to. EN 61000-4-5 specifies various different voltage levels and it is down to the designer to select the one that is appropriate and then choose the right TVS. The TVS in your question is this and, outlined in red is the important information: -

[image]

It is the important information because, for EN 61000-4-5 the pulse shape is 8/20 μs. This is the current pulse shape you get when shunting the indirect lightning surge with a low voltage TVS.

So, for the SMAJ58 device, the appropriate columns indicate a clamping voltage of 121 volts at 19 amps: -

[image]

This equals 2.299 kW (as per page 1 and the top picture in my answer).

> *Can anyone help me to identify the lightning protection voltage?*

But, you then need to look into EN 61000-4-5 and understand whether your chosen device is suitable for power lines or data lines. Looking at the physical size of the device I would definitely say it's not suitable for power lines hence, the indirect lightning source impedance will be about 42 Ω (from memory). And 19 amps through 42 Ω is 798 volts. If you add that to the clamping voltage of 121 volts you get 919 volts. This to me means that you'd be lucky to achieve a 1,000 open-circuit pulse withstand rating and definitely not 2,000 volts.

After all, it is a piddling small device for indirect lightning protection.

Comment: Thanks, Some electronic devices have 6kv surge protection. Does it means they have high voltage and current rating tvs diode, like 200V and 30A

Comment: No, it doesn't. A lot of ethernet products can handle 6 kV due to the isolating nature of the magnetics on the data lines. Then with non-isolated products that rely on TVS diodes, the lower the clamp voltage the easier a given package size will survive the peak current; if a TVS is rated at 8 volts then it will be surged with about the same current as a device rated at 80 volts (think about it) @Selva97

Comment: what does the term 6kv surge protection means, is there any specific hardware components used in the input power supply.

Comment: @Selva97 there are 1 kV, 2 kV, 4 kV and 6kV commonly used. The bigger the voltage, the greater the short circuit current and the bigger the current surge the TVS diode has to survive. The TVS you picked won't survive a 1 kV surge on data lines as per EN 61000-4-5. I don't understand your 2nd question in your comment.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I got it. I become confused because in IEC-61000-4-5 Standard, they mentioned the voltage standards like 25V -12A, 500V -250A,
Link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61000-4-5
In our datasheet they havent metioned like this standard, thats why i got confused.

Answer (score 0):

The VCL is the clamping voltage of the TVS diode. This means that anything at or above the 93.6V will be effectively shorted. The answer is yes, this will protect against the high voltages that you mentioned.

Comment: But only 93.6V, but according to standard IEC-61000-4-5, it should have Kilo volts of surge protection

Comment: @Selva97 it does. 93.6V is just the rating at which it is clamped. So regardless if you give it 100V or 6000V it will clamp at 93.6V. The device has the protection you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Vcl is the clamping voltage. It means that should a lightning strike occur, the max voltage on the rail will be about 93.6V (provided the skrike complies with the stated models. Which it generally should). According to the datasheet it is rated for IEC-61000-4-5 as seen from the snippet below:

[image]

Basically, the datasheet guarantees that the diode complies with the IEC-61000-4-5. If it can protect the device in question depends on where the static or lightning strike occurs and how the PCB layout.

Comment: can it handle voltage upto 6KV?